# Most efficient way to re-order my database table and display to web

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to MySQL, Just read the section of my book explaining it and now at the point where I'm applying it to the website I'm building.

I have the two following tables in my database:

```
Table Name: Transactions
+------------------+------------+-----------+--------+
| description      | date       | category  | amount |
+------------------+------------+-----------+--------+
| Internet         | 2013-01-04 | Bills     | $50.00 |
+------------------+------------+-----------+--------+
| Giant Eagle Trip | 2013-10-04 | Groceries | $30.00 |
+------------------+------------+-----------+--------+
| Car Insurance    | 2013-01-04 | Bills     | $90.00 |
+------------------+------------+-----------+--------+
| Starbucks        | 2013-09-04 | Coffee    |  $5.00 |
+------------------+------------+-----------+--------+
| Giant Eagle Trip | 2013-11-04 | Groceries | $15.00 |
+------------------+------------+-----------+--------+

Table Name: Categories
+------+-----------+
| rank | Name      |
+------+-----------+
|    1 | Bills     |
+------+-----------+
|    2 | Groceries |
+------+-----------+
|    3 | Coffee    |
+------+-----------+
```

On My website I want to take that transaction table and order it by category column. The trick is I don't want it ordered alphabetically, I want it ordered in the same order as the Categories table.  The final result I have displayed below:

```
+------------------+------------+-----------+--------+
| description      | date       | category  | amount |
+------------------+------------+-----------+--------+
| Internet         | 2013-01-04 | Bills     | $50.00 |
+------------------+------------+-----------+--------+
| Car Insurance    | 2013-01-04 | Bills     | $90.00 |
+------------------+------------+-----------+--------+
| Giant Eagle Trip | 2013-10-04 | Groceries | $30.00 |
+------------------+------------+-----------+--------+
| Giant Eagle Trip | 2013-11-04 | Groceries | $15.00 |
+------------------+------------+-----------+--------+
| Starbucks        | 2013-09-04 | Coffee    |  $5.00 |
+------------------+------------+-----------+--------+
```

I have thought of two ways to do this and they are as follows:

```
//Option A: using arrays
   //Get categories in correct order
   $query  = "select name 
              from Categories
              order by rank";
   $result = $db->query($query);
   $numOfCategories = $result->num_rows;
   for($i=0; $i<$numOfCategories; $i++) {
      $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
      $category[$i] = $row['name'];
   }

   //Get transactions and put in correct order
   $query  = "select *
              from Transactions";
   $result = $db->query($query);
   $numOfTransactions = $result->num_rows;

   for($i=0; $i<$numOfTransactions; $i++) {
      $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
      for($j=0; $j<$numOfCategories; $j++) {
         if ($category[$j] == $row['category']) {
            $tableRows[$j][] = $row;
         }
      }
   }

   //Display Table
   echo "<table>\n";
   for($i=0; $i<count($tableRows); $i++) {
      for($j=0; $j<count($tableRows[$i]); $j++) {
         echo "   <tr>\n";
         echo "      <td>".$tableRows[$i][$j]['description']."</td>\n";
         echo "      <td>".$tableRows[$i][$j]['date']."</td>\n";
         echo "      <td>".$tableRows[$i][$j]['category']."</td>\n";
         echo "      <td>".$tableRows[$i][$j]['amount']."</td>\n";
         echo "   </tr>\n";
      }
   }
   echo "</table><br><br>\n";

//Option B: using where in select query
   //Get categories in correct order
   $query  = "select name 
              from Categories
              order by rank";
   $result = $db->query($query);
   $numOfCategories = $result->num_rows;
   for($i=0; $i<$numOfCategories; $i++) {
      $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
      $category[$i] = $row['name'];
   }

   //Get transactions and display table
   echo "<table>\n";
   for($i=0; $i<$numOfCategories; $i++) {
      $query  = "select * 
                 from Transactions
                 where category = '".$category[$i]."'";
      $result = $db->query($query);
      for($j=0; $j<$result->num_rows; $j++) {
         $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
         echo "   <tr>\n";
         echo "      <td>".$row['description']."</td>\n";
         echo "      <td>".$row['date']."</td>\n";
         echo "      <td>".$row['category']."</td>\n";
         echo "      <td>".$row['amount']."</td>\n";
         echo "   </tr>\n";
      }
   }
   echo "</table><br><br>\n";
```

Which way is better and why, or is there another way that is even better than the ways (maybe using index feature in MySQL that my book didn't explain in much detail and/or using prepared statements that my book also didn't explain in much detail).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Categories.*, Transactions.*
FROM Categories
LEFT JOIN Transactions ON Categories.name = Transactions.Category
ORDER BY Categories.rank
```

I'd suggest not embedding the category names in your transactions table. While it's ok for a trivial example like this, it will end up sucking up a LOT of spaces to store redundant copies of all those category names. You should be storing the category IDs only. 4byte int v.s. however many bytes for the varchars will be a substantial savings if this table ever gets "big".

Comment: `categories.*` = `all fields in the categories table`

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM Transactions LEFT JOIN
   Categories ON Categories.Name = Transactions.category
```

#### [`More for LEFT JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html)